# Tabla editable no envia datos a Firebase

Tags: javascript, html, json, base-de-datos, firebase

Hice una tabla editable que tiene como atributo CONTENTEDITABLE, el form ya envia perfectamente datos a la base de datos Firebase. La tabla no me deja mandar el dato que pongo en la celda que tiene el ID septemberEntry dándome el error: index.js:5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'namedItem' of undefined at index:js:5 o sino que no es una función... que el value es nulo, etc, etc. Apenas sé algo de JS y honestamente no sé como resolverlo. Necesito que me haga otra colección en Firebase y me tome los datos de las celdas TD y me los guarde con su correspondiente ID. Alguna idea? Muchas gracias

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html lang="en">
            <head>
                <meta charset="UTF-8">
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
                <title>Heliconia tech</title>
                <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
            </head>
            <!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
            <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.17.1/firebase-app.js"></script>

            <!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
                https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->
            <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.17.1/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
            <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.17.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>

            <script>
            // Your web app's Firebase configuration
            var firebaseConfig = {
            };
            // Initialize Firebase
            firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
            firebase.analytics();
            </script>

            <body id="body">
                <div class="container">
                    <form id="clientForm">
                        <label for="name" autofocus>Nombre:</label>
                        <input type="text" id="name"><br>

                        <label for="birthDate">Fecha de nacimiento:</label>
                        <input type="date" id="birthDate"><br>

                        <label for="baptismDate">Fecha de bautismo:</label>
                        <input type="date" id="baptismDate"><br>

                        <label for="gender">Género:</label>
                        <select id="gender">
                            <option value="man" selected>Hombre</option> 
                            <option value="woman">Mujer</option>
                        </select><br>

                        <label for="group">Grupo:</label>
                        <select id="group">
                            <option value="ungido" selected>Ungido</option> 
                            <option value="anciano">Anciano</option>
                            <option value="siervoMinisterial">Siervo Ministerial</option>
                            <option value="precursorRegular">Precursor regular</option> 
                            <option value="otrasOvejas">Otras ovejas</option>
                        </select><br>
                    <br>
                    <table id="clientTable">
                        <tr>
                            <th class="tableText">Año de servicio </th>
                            <th class="tableText">Publicaciones</th>
                            <th class="tableText">Presentación<br> de videos</td>
                            <th class="tableText">Horas</th>
                            <th class="tableText">Revisitas</th>
                            <th class="tableText">Cursos<br> bíblicas</th>
                            <th class="tableText">Notas</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th contenteditable class="tableText">Septiembre</th>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="septemberEntry"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th contenteditable class="tableText">Octubre</th>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th contenteditable class="tableText">Noviembre</th>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th contenteditable class="tableText">Diciembre</th>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th contenteditable class="tableText">Enero</th>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th contenteditable class="tableText">Febrero</th>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th contenteditable class="tableText">Marzo</th>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th contenteditable class="tableText">Abril</th>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th contenteditable class="tableText">Mayo</th>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th contenteditable class="tableText">Junio</th>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th contenteditable class="tableText">Julio</th>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th contenteditable class="tableText">Agosto</th>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table><br>
                    <button id="buttonSubmit">Enviar</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <script src="js/index.js"></script>
            </body>
            </html>
```

Y este es el código JS

```
    var clientForm = document.getElementById('clientForm');
    var clientTable = document.getElementById('clientTable');
    var sep = clientTable.elements.namedItem('septemberEntry');

    var saveClient = (name,birthDate,baptismDate,gender,group) =>
        db.collection('Cliente').doc().set({
            name,
            birthDate,
            baptismDate,
            gender,
            group,
            septemberEntry
        })

    clientForm.addEventListener('submit', async e => {
        e.preventDefault();

        var name = clientForm['name'].value;
        var birthDate = clientForm['birthDate'].value;
        var baptismDate = clientForm['baptismDate'].value;
        var gender = clientForm['gender'].value;
        var group = clientForm['group'].value;
        var septemberEntry = sep.elements.namedItem('septemberEntry').value;   

        await saveClient(name,birthDate,baptismDate,gender,group, septemberEntry)
    })
```

Comment: Podrías empezar depurando los posibles elementos con error, poniendo un `console.log(sep);` y un `console.log(septemberEntry);` debajo de la declaración de cada uno para verificar la constitución de esos elementos.

Answer (score 0):

Si he entendido bien, quieres por ejemplo recoger los valores que haya en Septiembre para mandarlos a Firebase.

Primeramente hay que señalar que `namedItem()`no existe para los fines que intentas usarlo.

Siguiendo el enunciado inicial, una forma simple de recoger los datos para `Septiembre` o para cualquier otro mes sería:

1. Otorgar el `id` al `tr` donde estarían los datos de Septiembre.
2. Seleccionar todos los `td` de esa fila. Con [`querySelectoAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) es relativamente fácil. Ese método te crea un array con cada `td` de esa fila y luego puedes leer cada valor del `td`, cada `id`  o cualquier otro elemento del mismo. Cabe decir que `querySelectorAll()` sirve para seleccionar cualquier tipo de elementos, por cualquier tipo de selector, no solamente el `id`, sirve para seleccionar por clases, por nombres, por tipos de elementos, etc. Es una potente herramienta para agrupar fácilmente elementos.

Aparte de eso, estás dando el mismo `id` a todos los elementos. La especificación HTML indica que en un mismo documento no debería haber más de un elemento con el mismo `id`. Esto, aunque aparentemente no da error, será problemático al querer diferencia elementos por su `id` o querer operar con ellos.

Aislando el problema de `Firebase` y demás hice esta prueba que te puede servir. Para simplificar, puse solamente la tabla de Septiembre, pero puedes hacerlo con cualquier otro de los meses.

Otra cosa: en tu código original hay errores, hay etiquetas mal cerradas, debes corregir eso para evitar posibles problemas.

En esta prueba, al pulsar `Enviar` se seleccionan todas las `td` de Septiembre y se muestran los `id` y los valores de cada `td`. Así como lo imprimes, puedes crear con facilidad un array u otro objeto para enviarlo a Firebase. Es cuestión de adaptarlo en tu contexto. Espero te sirva.

```js
var clientForm = document.getElementById('clientForm');
var clientTable = document.getElementById('clientTable');
var rowSeptember = clientTable.querySelectorAll('#septemberEntry td');

document.getElementById("buttonSubmit").addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  rowSeptember.forEach(function(td) {
    console.log(`El ID es: ${td.id} y el contenido es: ${td.textContent}`);

  });
});
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th,
td {
  text-align: center;
}

tr {
  outline: thin solid;
}

table,
td,
th {
  border: 1px gray solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <form id="clientForm">
    <label for="name" autofocus>Nombre:</label>
    <input type="text" id="name">

    <label for="birthDate">Fecha de nacimiento:</label>
    <input type="date" id="birthDate">

    <label for="baptismDate">Fecha de bautismo:</label>
    <input type="date" id="baptismDate">

    <label for="gender">Género:</label>
    <select id="gender">
      <option value="man" selected>Hombre</option>
      <option value="woman">Mujer</option>
    </select>

    <label for="group">Grupo:</label>
    <select id="group">
      <option value="ungido" selected>Ungido</option>
      <option value="anciano">Anciano</option>
      <option value="siervoMinisterial">Siervo Ministerial</option>
      <option value="precursorRegular">Precursor regular</option>
      <option value="otrasOvejas">Otras ovejas</option>
    </select><br>
    <br>
    <table id="clientTable">
      <tr>
        <th class="tableText">Año</th>
        <th class="tableText">Publicaciones</th>
        <th class="tableText">Videos
          <th class="tableText">Horas</th>
          <th class="tableText">Revisitas</th>
          <th class="tableText">Cursos</th>
          <th class="tableText">Notas</th>
      </tr>
      <tr id="septemberEntry">
        <th contenteditable class="tableText">Septiembre</th>
        <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="td1">1</td>
        <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="td2">2</td>
        <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="td3">3</td>
        <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="td4">4</td>
        <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="td5">5</td>
        <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="td6">6</td>


      </tr>
      <tr>
    </table>
    <p>* Las celdas se pueden editar.</p>
    <button id="buttonSubmit">Enviar</button>
  </form>
</div>
```